# How to find a normal abelian subgroup in a solvable group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Nontrivial Subgroup of a Solvable Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100567/a-nontrivial-subgroup-of-a-solvable-group)

If $H$ is nontrivial normal subgroup of the solvable group $G$, then how can I show that there is a nontrivial subgroup $A\leq H$ such that $A$ is abelian and normal in $G$?

I am looking for hints so that I can create my own solution.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hint: Isomorphism theorems

Comment: Yes, right! Because using third theorem isomorphism $[H\cap G^{(m-1)}\cap G^{(m)}]=1$. And for the second relation $(H\cap G^{(m-1)})G^{(m)}<G^{(m-1)}$ since $G^{(m)}<G^{(m-1)}$. Is it right?

Comment: See the answer by Arturo Magidin at
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100567/a-nontrivial-subgroup-of-a-solvable-group.

Comment: @stacy: Did you get your answer? :-)

Comment: See [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59254/normal-abelian-subgroup-of-a-solvable-group) for a good idea. It doesn't have any answers explicitly posted, but it will get you started.

Comment: @Maths Lover: I edited your question; please make sure it is the same as the one you asked.

Comment: @eric stucky : thank you :) yes it's the same

Comment: Is G finite ?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Amr , that is not mentioned

Comment: The question that for which this was closed as a duplicate has restrictions regarding the method of proof. I don't think that this should have been closed since this question can use more advanced methods in its answers.

Answer (score 2):

Hints (for you to prove):

1) It is true that

$$H\geq H'\geq\ldots\geq H^{(n)}=1\,\, ,\,\, \text{for some}\,\,\,n\in\Bbb N$$

2) Show that $\,H^{(n-1)}\triangleleft G\,\;\;$ (Yes, not only in $\,H\,$ ...!)

Comment: Why don't post your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100567/a-nontrivial-subgroup-of-a-solvable-group)?

Comment: Thank you for this hints ! 
i think I can slove it as follows , 
H is normal subgroup of G , so H is solvabe also .
let 1=Hn is normal of H(n-1) is normal of ... is normal of H 
where H(i-1)\Hi is abelian let Hi = 1 then H(i-1) = H(n-1) 
and H(n-1) is abelian from this , then H(n-1) is normal of G 
done ! 

Is this right ?!

Comment: Well: $\,H^{(n-1)}\,$ is abelian because its derived group is trivial, but he's normal in $\,G\,$ *not* for being abelian (there're lots of groups with non-normal abelian subgroups!), but because it is a characteristic (even fully invariant) subgroup of a normal subgroup of $\,G\,$...

Comment: but I didn't study derived Group or characteristic ! it's not mentioned untill this moment in my text ! i use dummit and foote ! is there another way to do it ? can you give me example to a group whose a abelian subgroup , and this subgroup is not normal ?

Comment: The subgroup $\,\{(1)\,,\,(12)\}\leq S_3\,$ is abelian and very not normal, to give perhaps the minimal and easiest example.

Comment: About my answer: can you give the exact place where this exercise is in Dummit & Foote?

Comment: page 106 , the exercise number 11 , it's in section 4 in chapter 3 which talks about holder program and composition series .

Comment: Ok: the commutator subgroups (or derived subgroup) was defined in exercises 40-41 in page 89 (section 3.1), but characteristic subgroup indeed is presented later (page 135 or so). Anyway, you can prove directly that the commutator subgroup of a normal subgroup is again normal in the big group...

Comment: Read "Added 2" in the answer by Arturo Magidin in the link provided by YACP above. I think it works out an answer using only the available info in D&F book at page 89. It is pretty messy and long since after some pages, with some new stuff, the claim follows pretty easily, as in my answer.